# What are the main websites and mailing lists for PhD applications in computer science?

Tags: phd, application

I'm currently completing a master degree and would like to continue working in research (public or private). My main interested are computer science, operations research, combinatorial optimization and cybersecurity.

Is there an international mailing list for applications in these domains ?